# Trouble iterating through a hashset

Tags: java, file, iterator, hashset

My problem is when I run my main method, nothing prints.
I am pretty new to `HashSet`s and I fear that it doesn't work because of something really stupid. 
`dic` was originally an `ArrayList` and i am just trying to convert it to `HashSet`s for efficiency.

```
private Set<String>dic = new HashSet<String>(100000);
public void dictionary(){//reads/intializes arraylist dic from a file
    File data = new File("dictionaryForJava.txt");
    Scanner scanner=null;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(data);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            dic.add(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {}
    if(scanner!=null)scanner.close(); // need if if file missing
}
public void print () throws IOException{
     Iterator it = dic.iterator();   
     while(it.hasNext())
         {
              String value =(String)it.next();
              System.out.println(value);  
         }
}
public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException{
    words test = new words();
    test.dictionary();
    test.print();
}
```

Comment: It is adding anything at all in dictionary() method? You need to print the exception in catch block. It seems either you are having FileNotFoundException (or) nothing to read.

Comment: Don't hide exceptions (as you do with the `FileNotFoundException`). At the very least, log an error to console.

Comment: I've just run it and for me it's working. Of course only if the named file exists and contains appropriate content. I agree to the other comments. You shouldn't ignore the FileNotFoundException.

Comment: This code worked for me also. Read in the lines of a file and printed them back out.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite possible that the file `dictionaryForJava.txt` is not being found. You must NOT eat the exceptions without at least printing some debugging information, try this:

```
catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {fnfe.printStackTrace();}
```

The above will show you in the console if there was some problem reading the file.

Comment: the problem isn't with reading the file in because it works perfectly when everything is an arrayList

Comment: @LouisB anyway, don't eat the exception, handle it and do something with it. It's an awful practice to leave an empty `catch` block.

Comment: Load this into Eclipse or your favourite IDE, set a breakpoint at the start of dictionary() and step through the code